# Jmeter interpreting results in simple terms

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

So I'm trying to test a website, and trying to interpret the aggregate report by "common sense" (as I tried looking up the meanings of each result and i cannot understand how they should be interpreted).

TEST 1

```
Thread Group: 1
Ramp-up: 1
Loop Count: 1

 - Samples 1
 - Average 645
 - Median 645
 - 90% Line 645
 - Min 645
 - Max 645 
 - Throughput 1.6/sec
```

So I am under the assumption that the first result is the best outcome.

TEST 2

```
Thread Group: 5
Ramp-up: 1
Loop Count: 1

 - Samples 1
 - Average 647
 - Median 647
 - 90% Line 647
 - Min 643
 - Max 652 
 - Throughput 3.5/sec
```

I am assuming TEST 2 result is not so bad, given that the results are near TEST 1.

TEST 3

```
Thread Group: 10
Ramp-up: 1
Loop Count: 1

 - Samples 1
 - Average 710
 - Median 711
 - 90% Line 739
 - Min 639
 - Max 786 
 - Throughput 6.2/sec
```

Given the dramatic difference, I am assuming that if 10 users concurrently requested for the website, it will not perform well. How would this set of tests be interpreted in simple terms?

Comment: Something is wrong in this results , In  TEST 1: For sample count 1 ,getting 3.5 throughput is never possible with average latency of 645 ms. Send me exact sample count in your report.

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as available resources.

Response Times are dependent on many things and following are critical factors:

1. Server Machine Resources (Network, CPU, Disk, Memory etc)
2. Server Machine Configuration (type of server, number of nodes, no. of threads etc)
3. Client Machine Resources (Network, CPU, Disk, Memory etc)

As you understand it is about mostly how server is busy responding to other requests and how much client machine is busy generating/processing Load (I assume you run all 10 users in single machine)

Best way to know the actual reason is by `Monitoring` these resources using `nmon for linux` & `perfmon or task manager for Windows` (or any other monitoring tool) and understand the differences when you ran `1, 5, 10` users.

---

Apart from Theory part, I assume that it is talking time because of your are putting the sudden load where the server takes time in processing the previous requests.

Are you using client and server on the same machine? If Yes, that would tell us that the system resources are utilized both for client threads (10 threads) and server threads.

---

Resposne Time = client sends the request to server TIME + server processing TIME + Server sends the resposne to the client TIME

In your case, it might be one or more TIME's increased.

If you have good bandwidth, then it might be `server processing time`

Answer (score 0):

Your results are confusing.

For thread count of 5 and 10, you have given the same number of samples - 1. It should be 1 (1 thread), 5 ( 5 threads) and 10 samples for 10 threads. Your experiment has statistically less samples to conclude anything. You should model your load in such a way that the 1 thread load is sustained for a longer period before you ramp up 5 and 10 threads. If you are running a small test to assess the the scalability of your application, you could do something like

1 thread - 15  mins

5 threads - 15 mins

10 threads - 15 mins

provide the observations for each of the 15 min period. If you application is really scaling, it should maintain the same response time even under increased load.

Looking at your results, I don't see any issues with your application. There is nothing varying. Again, you don't have much samples that can lead to statistically relevant conclusion.